# Why is my Javascript not creating a div within a class?

Tags: javascript, html

[Edit: Fixed an attempted fix I'd accidentally left in]
I'm taking a SkillShare course (I know, grain of salt with that) to create a responsive image gallery for my freelance art page. The current goal is to populate the page with images using Javascript. I'm trying to create a div called 'image' within a class called 'image-grid'; 'image' should contain a drawing from a folder called 'images'.

My pertinent HTML:

```
<body>

    <div class="gallery-container">
        <h2 class="gallery-title">Illustrations and Comics by Gwen</h2> 
    
    <div class="image-grid">
 
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

My Javscript:

```
const imagesList = [
    {
        imageUrl: "images/DyingToLive.png",
        title: "Dying to Live",
    },
];

const imageGrid = document.querySelector(".image-grid");

const populateImages = () => {
    imagesList.forEach((i) => {
        const image = document.createElement("div");
        image.classList.add("image");
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = i.imageUrl;
        img.alt = i.title;
        image.appendChild(img);
        imageGrid.appendChild(image);
    });
};

populateImages();
```

Teacher's version of the js:
[image: Teacher's version of js]

Apologies if I'm missing something simple. My partner and I both went over it line by line for discrepancies. I have my own image name/title and I'm not using thumbnails so I went with imageUrl instead of thumbUrl. Apart from that, it looks identical to me.

The problem is that when I fire it up in my browser, there's no image, and when I view source, there's no sign of an 'image' div inside that image-grid class. Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've written `div.classList.add("image");` instead of `image.classList.add("image");`

Comment: Sorry about that, I'd been messing about with various elements to see if anything changed. (Basically like trying to find the stud in a wall by smashing holes with a crowbar.) I fixed that and it still doesn't work, however.

Answer (score 0):

Seems `div.classList.add("image");` is useless since `div` is not defined at that time and other elements are created by `document`,try to remove it

```js
const imagesList = [
    {
        imageUrl: "https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iXwouvL_DCbc/v0/150x-1.jpg",
        title: "Dying to Live",
    },
];

const imageGrid = document.querySelector(".image-grid");

const populateImages = () => {
    imagesList.forEach((i) => {
        const image = document.createElement("div");
        //div.classList.add("image");
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = i.imageUrl;
        img.alt = i.title;
        image.appendChild(img);
        imageGrid.appendChild(image);
    });
};

populateImages();
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="gallery-container">
        <h2 class="gallery-title">Illustrations and Comics by Gwen</h2> 
    
    <div class="image-grid">
 
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
div.classList.add("image");
```

to

```
image.classList.add("image");
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to change that back when I was messing around with different aspects in blind and desperate trial and error. It still doesn't work, though.

Comment: where did you put you script tag, in the header? or somewhere in the body

Comment: In the body, at the bottom. I only stuck the end body tag there so people wouldn't spot that as a potential flaw.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have img name with DyingToLive.png change name to exist img name.